# Is there an equivalent of redis command pipeline in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pipeline

I am debugging a slow API endpoint in a web app which uses mongodb as storage. It turns out the request send 8 different queries to MongoDB, and group the data together to return. The MongoDB lives on another host, so the request involves 8 roundtrips.

These 8 requests don't have any dependency among themselves, so if I can send the 8 queries in a batch, or in parallel, a lot of time can be saved.

I am wondering if Mongo supports something like Redis's pipeline, or maybe send a script (like a lua script in Redis) for fetching data, so that I can get all data in one go?

If not, is there a way to send the querys in parallel? (The app is based on python/tornado/pymongo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no pipeline-like mechanism in MongoDB.

I would try using [server-side scripts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/).

Comment: "MongoDB’s aggregation framework is modeled on the concept of data processing pipelines. Documents enter a multi-stage pipeline that transforms the documents into an aggregated result." [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline)

Comment: @SteveRossiter In Redis pipelines can process multiple commands in one query. On MongoDB pipelines are only for fetching data.

Comment: oh ok I may have misunderstood the question. The question is not suggesting any updates or inserts though so if the queries are on the same collection then a single aggregation request would still work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options for this kind of thing in mongodb all of which can be accessed by the [python driver pymonogo](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/).

The best way (IMHO) is the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) which allows you to build a pipeline. However, some of the functionality is limited by mongodb version and whether you have sharded clusters.

Other options include [map-reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/) or [simple operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#single-purpose-aggregation-operations).